# force folder structure and names in a repository using eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, lint

I'm looking to force a structure of names in a specific path for a folder and it's sub folders

**not only the styling of the names (kebab, camel) but the actual names of the folders and files**

lets take for an example the following paths

```
./src/modules/module1
./src/modules/module2
./src/modules/module3
```

each of the provided path should force sub folders with the names

```
services
components
style
```

creating a nested folder with a different name on those path should not be valid

so the end result should be something like that:

```
./src/modules/module1/services (valid)
./src/modules/module1/components (valid)
./src/modules/module2/components (valid)
./src/modules/module1/banana (not valid)
./src/modules/orange/yellow (valid)
```

is eslint the right tool for that? any specific plugin I should use ?

I could only find a solution for the styling of the names but didn't find anything for a fixed named structure

I'm using type-script in reactJS project and looking for a solution that is not coupled to any IDE

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out FoldersLint, it should do the job.

https://github.com/denisraslov/folderslint

This is basically how it works:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

> is eslint the right tool for that? any specific plugin I should use ?

Yes, my [eslint-plugin-project-structure](https://github.com/Igorkowalski94/eslint-plugin-project-structure) package is perfect for this.

Here is the list of current features:

✅ Validation of project structure (Any files/folders outside the structure will be considered an error).
✅ Validation of folder and file names.
✅ Name case validation.
✅ Name regex validation.
✅ File extension validation (Support for all extensions).
✅ Inheriting the parent's name (The child inherits the name of the folder in which it is located).
✅ Folder recursion (You can nest a given folder structure recursively).
✅ Forcing a nested/flat structure for a given folder.

> lets take for an example the following paths

> ./src/modules/module1
> ./src/modules/module2
> ./src/modules/module3

> each of the provided path should force sub folders with the names

> services
> components
> style

> creating a nested folder with a different name on those path should not be valid

> ./src/modules/module1/services (valid)
> ./src/modules/module1/components (valid)
> ./src/modules/module2/components (valid)
> ./src/modules/module1/banana (not valid)
> ./src/modules/orange/yellow (valid)

From what I understand from your description `./src/modules/orange/yellow (valid)`
was supposed to be `./src/modules/orange/yellow (not valid)`.

Here is a configuration that meets these requirements.

1. You can only create folders in the `modules` folder. The name of the folders must meet `camelCase`.
2. Each folder in the `modules` folder can only have 3 subfolders named `components`, `style` and `services`.

```
{
  "structure": {
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "src",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "modules",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "/^${{camelCase}}$/",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "services",
                    "children": [
                      // ... rules for services folder
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "components",
                    "children": [
                      // ... rules for components folder
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "style",
                    "children": [
                      // ... rules for style folder
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "extension": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here you will find a detailed description of the API.
https://github.com/Igorkowalski94/eslint-plugin-project-structure#api

Comment: When promoting your own library/website, please be so kind as to disclose it in the answer. See [how not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eslint repo-structure plugin, it receives a config file with your project folder and files structures and validates naming/casing.

https://github.com/eduhdm/eslint-plugin-repo-structure